# MongoAlchemy Document Encode to JSON via Flask-MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I think I am missing something small here.  I am testing out Python framework Flask and Flask-MongoAlchemy, and want to convert an entity into JSON output.  Here is my code (abstracted):

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mongoalchemy import MongoAlchemy

try:
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
except:
    pass

#a bunch of code to open the mongoDB

class ClassA(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    field1 = db.StringField()
    field2 = db.BoolField()

@app.route('/api/classA', methods=['GET'])
def api_list_all
    a = ClassA.query.all()
    result = []
    for b in a:
        result.append(b.wrap())
    print result
    return json.dumps(result)
```

Without the json.dumps line, the print statement prompt the right result.  But only if I run the json.dumps on result, it yields:

**TypeError: ObjectId('...') is not JSON serializable**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is a mongo document of some sort that contains ObjectId-type content, which you'll have to tell json how to deserialize. You'll have the same problem with other mongo-specific types, such as ReferenceField(), EmbeddedDocumentField(), etc.
You have to write a deserialization function that you can pass to json. What I use is:

```
def encode_model(obj, recursive=False):
    if obj is None:
        return obj
    if isinstance(obj, (mongoengine.Document, mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument)):
        out = dict(obj._data)
        for k,v in out.items():
            if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
                if k is None:
                    out['_id'] = str(v)
                    del(out[k])
                else:
                    # Unlikely that we'll hit this since ObjectId is always NULL key
                    out[k] = str(v)
            else:
                out[k] = encode_model(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet):
        out = encode_model(list(obj))
    elif isinstance(obj, ModuleType):
        out = None
    elif isinstance(obj, groupby):
        out = [ (g,list(l)) for g,l in obj ]
    elif isinstance(obj, (list)):
        out = [encode_model(item) for item in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, (dict)):
        out = dict([(k,encode_model(v)) for (k,v) in obj.items()])
    elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        out = str(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
        out = {'ObjectId':str(obj)}
    elif isinstance(obj, (str, unicode)):
        out = obj
    elif isinstance(obj, float):
        out = str(obj)
    else:
        raise TypeError, "Could not JSON-encode type '%s': %s" % (type(obj), str(obj))
    return out
```

Then you'd process the result as:

```
return json.dumps(result, default=encode_model)
```

or something to this effect.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may have to process other fields over time. I keep finding things that I need to store as str() but don't want to do it generically (ie don't want to remove the raise TypeError).

Comment: what does "mongoengine" refer to in this function?

Comment: yourfriendzak - `import mongoengine` The types (Document, EmbeddedDocument, etc.) are defined on the mongodb handler, which in this case is mongoengine. It could just as easily be pymongo, or mongoalchemy or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `query.raw_output()` method to have that query instance return raw Python dictionaries instead of a Python object. With a dictionary it becomes easy to encode to JSON using `json.dumps()`:

```
import json
q=db.query(MyObject)
q.raw_output()
json.dumps(q.first())
```

Reference http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/expressions/query.html#mongoalchemy.query.Query.raw_output

Answer (score 0):

Combining the previous two answers, you should be able to do something like this:

```py
from bson import json_util

# ... 

@app.route('/api/classA', methods=['GET'])
def api_list_all
    a = ClassA.query.all()
    result = []
    for b in a:
        result.append(b.wrap())
    print result
    return json_utils.dumps(result) # Change here.
```